# Problem with a char string, reads inputs wrong

Tags: c

So I got a void function (ler_frase) that is supposed to read a char input and stop when the user presses enter or when the user types " - " the hyfen (lines 31-36), it's supposed to assign a value of 1 to a verifier  global valriable (v), which is of type int and is set to zero globally (line 21).
But the function reads a hyfen " - " even when there are none, always setting the verifier to 1 and thus activating a break inside a if (lines 79-82). Any ideas on why this happens and what do I have to do? tyty.

```
#include<stdio.h>

typedef struct Pessoa{
    char funcionario[100];
    float salario;
}pessoa;

typedef struct Endereco{
    char rua[100];
    int numero;
}endereco;

typedef struct Empresa{
    char nome[100];
    endereco _endereco;
    pessoa _pessoa[2];
}empresa;

int N=2;
empresa emp[10];
int v=0;

void ler_frase(char* frase, int tamanho_maximo){
    int i;
    do
    {
        fgets(frase, tamanho_maximo, stdin);
        fflush(stdin);
        for (i = 0; i < tamanho_maximo && frase[i] != '\0'; i++)
        {
            if ( frase[i] == '-' )
            {
                frase[i] = '\0';
                v=1;
                break;
            }
            if ( frase[i] == '\n' )
            {
                frase[i] = '\0';
                break;
            }
        }
    } while ( i == 0 );
}

void ler_empresa(int i){
    printf("=== Entre com os dados da empresa %d:\n", i+1);
    printf("Nome: ");
    fflush(stdin);
    ler_frase(emp[i].nome, 100);
}

void ler_endereco(int i){

    printf("Rua: ");
    ler_frase(emp[i]._endereco.rua, 100);
    printf("Numero: ");
    scanf("%d", &emp[i]._endereco.numero);
    fflush(stdin);
}

void ler_funcionario(int i){
    int j;
    for(j=0;j<2;j++){
        printf("== Entre com os dados do funcionario %d:\n", j+1);
        printf("Nome: ");
        fflush(stdin);
        ler_frase(emp[i]._pessoa[j].funcionario, 100);
        printf("Salario: ");
        scanf("%f", &emp[i]._pessoa[j].salario);
    }
}

int main(){
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<N;i++){
        ler_empresa(i);
        if ( v = 1 ){
            N=i;
            break;
        }
        ler_endereco(i);
        ler_funcionario(i);
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n\n=================================================================\n");
    printf("Empresa\t\tEndereco\t\tFuncionario\tSalario");
    printf("\n=================================================================\n");
    for(i=0;i<N;i++){
        printf("%s\t\t%s,%d\t\t\t\t%s\t%.2f\n\t\t\t\t\t\t%s\t%.2f\n", emp[i].nome, emp[i]._endereco.rua, emp[i]._endereco.numero, emp[i]._pessoa[0].funcionario, emp[i]._pessoa[0].salario, emp[i]._pessoa[1].funcionario, emp[i]._pessoa[1].salario);
        printf("-----------------------------------------------------------------\n");
        }
    }
```

Ok, for some context that may help: This is a project I am working on which requires me to create 3 structures, a worker structure (pessoa), an address structure (endereco), and a company structure (empresa). I must create these so that the company structure has an address, which by itself has a street name and building number, and two workers, which individually have names and wages. So that explains the structures. Now for the purpose of the "ler" functions, each one is supposed to read what it was named after(i.e. the ler_endereco is supposed to read both the street name and number). And finally in the main I summon the functions I created, checking the verifier variable in the if in line 79, to read all the inputs a company needs and then print them out to the user to read.

Comment: `if ( v = 1 )` --> `if ( v == 1 )`

Comment: `fflush(stdin);` is undefined behavior under the C standard, unless the input stream is "seekable" (MS is the only compiler I know that uses that)

Comment: @kaylum YESS!! You've fixed it TYSM!!!!